# Neatly Printing Instructions in Pygame

Tags: python-2.7, fonts, pygame

I'm simply trying to display instructions at the beginning of my game using pygame. Of course I could go through and specify a position for each individual line, but I'm trying to do this efficiently. Every time I search for a simple method, someone is only doing one line and so they don't need a changing y-position. My problem is that every line is printing at the same y-position, despite my attempts. I've printed n to make sure it is changing. I don't understand why the position won't change with it. Also, I've added a -225 to my centerx position because for some reason the function is making this value off-centered. I may be using it wrong, I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated.

```
textlist = [instructionstitle, line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6]
for i in textlist:
    textpos = i.get_rect()
    textpos.centerx = background.get_rect().centerx - 225
    n = textlist.index(i)
    textpos.centery = 25*n + 25
    def show(i):
        screen.blit(i, [textpos.centerx, textpos.centery])
def instructions():
    screen.blit(background, [0, 0])
    for i in textlist:
        show(i)
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your show() function is inside the for loop for reasons I don't understand. By doing that, you have in your textpos variable, the value that was set to textpos in the last run of the for loop. So, yes, of course, the y position will not update! You don't need two for loops, one to set textpos and another to call show(). What you need is a simple rearrangement to allow for updating of your textpos variable correctly.

```
def show(i):    
    textpos = i.get_rect()    
    textpos.centerx = background.get_rect().centerx - 255
    n = textlist.index(i)
    textpos.centery = 25*n + 25
    screen.blit(i, [textpos.centerx, textpos.centery])
```

The instructions() function can work as is. Here, I'm assuming your textlist consists of surfaces rendered using the pygame Font module, i.e, something like this

`fntInst = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
instructionstitle = fntInst.render('Instructions', False, black)`.

And, as far as I can see it, the centerx position is not shifted. The position you set for the text surface is from where the top left corner of the surface will be rendered. So, if you want your text in the center, what you need to do is get the size of the surface generated using Font. You can do something like `fntInst.size('Instructions')` and subtract this size from the centerx value. A fixed 255 will not center all lines since the length of each line will differ, instead all your lines will be aligned the same.